# Ways of reading through files

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I'm writing a number of ksh scripts that cycle through a text file, processing it a line at a time.
I tend to use

```
while read X1 X2 X3 X4
do
    <process line>
done < $INFILE
```

but a colleague who did a similar thing used

```
IFS="
"
for LINE in `cat $INFILE`
do
    <process line>
done
```

He uses 'cut'  to parse the variables that I get automatically, but apart from that, are there any advantages or disadvantages to either approach?  How would others do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You're definitely on the right track. your colleague is using unneeded/extra processes, especially calling `cut`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `while read` is more memory efficient, and also splits on lines where the `for LINE in` notation splits on 'words'.  If there are blanks in the lines, then lines will be split.

So, unless there's a very good reason to use the `$(cat $INFILE)` notation (in `bash`, you could use `$(<$INFILE)` which is more efficient), the `while read` is the better choice.

Comment: He sets $IFS to <nl>, so lines don't split (see the first 2 lines of my 2nd codeblock)

Comment: Hmmm...yes, I suppose so...but if the line needs to be split into four fields, that's not as good as using `while read`.